# Relationship among different classifiers of a model in multiclass problems

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, pytorch, multiclass-classification, multi-output

Suppose we are fitting a LogisticRegression model with scikit-learn, or the same model with pytorch. In multiclass problems, the strategy OneVsRest will fit a different classifier for each of the labels of the dataset. For each classifier, the class will be fitted against all the other classes.
I want to ask: do you know if there is some research paper or some evidence of a relationship among the different classifiers? I mean, each classifier will have its own weights. Will modifying the vector of weights of one classifier also impact the performance of the other classifiers?